# I am a U.S. permanent resident. Can I get a Schengen visa in Seattle?

Tags: visas, schengen, seattle

I am a U.S. resident living in Seattle, WA. Can I get a Schengen visa in Seattle? It could be any European country. I don't want to fly to SF or LA.

Comment: If there is an embassy, consulate of an official visa centre of that country in Seatle, then yes, of course.

Comment: I need to do something similar, but while under a **J-1** visa. I asked the French consulate in Seattle if I could apply there and they said ``Normally no, but you can ask the consulate general in San Francisco'', which I did but got no answer (asked them again a few days ago). I think since you're a resident you'll be OK, but just providing another data point.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you can't apply to just any Schengen country for a visa. You must apply to the country that is the main destination, or failing that, the country that is your first point of entry.

Secondly, none of the major European countries maintain a consulate in or near Seattle (that's France, Germany, The Netherlands, Belgium, Spain, Italy, Austria). Your nearest consulates will be in Los Angeles or San Francisco. I didn't check all the Schengen countries, but it's unlikely that the smaller ones will have a presence in Seattle if the major ones don't. Belgium has an honorary consul in Seattle, but visa matters are referred to Los Angeles.

Comment: You *can* apply to just any Schengen country for a visa if you are willing to plan a trip to whichever Schengen country is most convenient to apply to.

Comment: You forgot about Vancouver (see my answer below).

Answer (score 3):

There are no Schengen consulates/embassies in Washington state. The closest Schengen consulates to Seattle are located in Vancouver, BC. And at the very least the Dutch embassy [does allow you](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/109340/9009) to apply for a visa there as a Green Card holder living in Seattle.

So plan an itinerary where the majority of your stay is in a country which has a consulate in Vancouver and you can apply for a visa without traveling too far.